# I have multiple select chosen. Why it is taking so much time to render 30000 option?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I have more than 30000 data in the select tag. I am converting select tag into multi select chosen drop down. It is taking time and finally browser message comes saying that Page Unrespocive. Please help if any body have solution of this issue.

Comment: _“I have more than 30000 data in the select tag”_ - what, initially already, when the page loads? Then why are you even wondering about performance issues…? If you need the user to chose from that many options, then a select field is rather the wrong choice to begin with IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is an insane amount for 1 selectlist. I suggest you break it into smaller pieces. It's too many DOM elements :)

It also has usability issues, 30k options is an aweful lot of options. If you have that many options, you have to assume that the user knows what they're looking for and type it in (nobody is going to look for something in that list).
If that is the case, you could simple store it into an javascript array, and make a sort of auto complete.